# RGB 24 to BitMap Resulting in Black Image

Tags: c#, image, bitmap

I can't quite seem to wrap my brain around images and converting them from a `byte[]` of raw RGB colors to a `BitMap`. I found one solution that allows me to convert an RGB 24bpp `byte[]` to a `BitMap` using `SetPixel`, but I have read that using `LockBits` is much faster, so I am trying to figure out how to do it that way.

Using the `SetPixel` method, I am getting an inverted image using:

```
public static Bitmap CreateBitmap24bppRgb(byte[] bmpData, int width, int height)
{
    var bmp = new Bitmap(width, height, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
    var pos = 0;
    for (var y = 0; y < height; y++)
    {
        for (var x = 0; x < width; x++)
        {
            bmp.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(bmpData[pos], bmpData[pos + 1], bmpData[pos + 2]));
                pos += 3;
        }
    }

    return bmp;
}
```

Which I can't quite seem to figure out how to invert. But when I try to use `LockBits`, the image is just black, and I am unsure what I am doing wrong, it seems quite straight forward.

```
public static Bitmap CreateBitmap24bppRgb(byte[] data, int width, int height)
{
    var bmp = new Bitmap(width, height, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);

    //Create a BitmapData and Lock all pixels to be written 
    var bmpData = bmp.LockBits(
                         new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height),
                         ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, bmp.PixelFormat);

    //Copy the data from the byte array into BitmapData.Scan0
    for (int y = 0; y < bmp.Height - 1; y++)
    {
        Marshal.Copy(data, y * bmp.Width, bmpData.Scan0 bmpData.Stride);
    }


    //Unlock the pixels
    bmp.UnlockBits(bmpData);

    return bmp;
}
```

I'm just curious what is going wrong here?

Comment: Bitmap data is *usually* stored upside down.  Your Marshal.Copy() method looks like nonsense, post code that can actually compile.  The 3rd argument should probably be bmpData.Scan0 + (bmp.Height - y - 1) * bmpData.Stride.

Comment: Besides Hans' comments: What exactly do you __do__ with the `data` during your lockBits?  You would have to __set__ some pixels' channels there..!  Look e.g. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26224095/how-to-find-the-difference-between-two-images/26225153#26225153) for an example of a working lockBits code. There are many more, of course..

Answer (score 4):

If you're creating a new bitmap, instead of modifying an existing one, there's no reason to use `LockBits` or `Marshal.Copy`.

Just go with [the `Bitmap` constructor that takes a pointer to pixel data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zy1a2d14%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
public static Bitmap CreateBitmap24bppRgb(byte[] data, int width, int height)
{
    GCHandle pin = GCHandle.Alloc(data, GCHandleType.Pinned);
    var bmp = new Bitmap(width, height,
                         (width * 3 + 3) / 4 * 4,
                         PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb,
                         Marshal.UnsafeAddrOfPinnedArrayElement(data, 0));
    bmp = (Bitmap)bmp.Clone(); // workaround the requirement that the memory address stay valid
                               // the clone step can also crop and/or change PixelFormat, if desired
    GCHandle.Free(pin);
    return bmp;
}
```

(or use an `unsafe` block, `pinned` keyword, and a pointer)