# Sequential PrintScreens Comparison, Generate a difference image?

Tags: c#, image, performance, bitmap, system.drawing

i am developing a application that save a printscreen at a regular interval, let's say 10 seconds.

In general the images are very similar, sometimes equal, so i came with the idea to create a bitmap that represents the difference between the current printscreen and the previous one.

To achieve this, i am comparing the 2 images, pixel by pixel, and when they are equal, i am setting the pixel with a Transparent Color (in the original code, i am using `Bitmap.LockBits` for a better performance):

```
for (var x = 0; x < width; y++)
for (var y = 0; y < height; y++)
{
   var oldColor = lastPrint.GetPixel(x, y);
   var color = currentPrint.GetPixel(x, y);

   if (oldColor == color)
   {
        differencePrint.SetPixel(x, y, Color.Transparent);
   }
}
```

To recover the image, i get the first printscreen and replace with the sequential bitmaps.

```
private void MergePrints()
    {
        var lastBitmap = new BitMap(firstPrint);
        foreach (var print in prints.OrderBy(e => e.Date))
        {
            using (var difference = new Bitmap(print.Image))
            {
                 using (var grfx = Graphics.FromImage(lastBitmap))
                 {
                     grfx.DrawImage(difference, 0, 0);
                 }                 
            }

            lastBitmap.Save(print.id + ".png");
        }
        lastBitmap.Dispose();
    }
```

My question is: Is there a better way to generate a object that represents the difference between the 2 images, other than a new image with transparent pixels? Maybe a new class? but this class need to be persisted and of course "smaller" than a bitmap, currently i am persisting the bitmap as byte[] after comprrsing it using 7zip algorithm.

Comment: Are you asking simply for a data access object that will hold your differences?  In this case, it's just a list of `System.Drawing.Point` i.e. you just need to store the x,y of the common areas, That seems to be all you need - you already have the functionality to create a new image given that information.

Comment: yes, but instead of a list of common pixels, i need a list of not common pixels, it would be something like a Dictionary<Point, Color> representing the differences. but if im going to this aproach, i also need to persist the dictionary, what would be the best way to persist it this dictionary? a subtable with each row representing a pixel?

Comment: Currently you are still using bitmap which is array of pixel colors. If changes are not big (means there will be a lot of transparent pixels), then much more efficiently will be to only store a list of coordinates (`x`,`y`) and corresponding new colors. Something like `List<Tuple<int, int, Color>>`. Drawing old bitmap and then updating points from such list will provide you with the new bitmap. Other option is to use specialized container for such things: `GIF` should do, if you accept image loss, then `MPEG`, etc. They use same idea of key-frames and changes.

Comment: @Sinatr Sorry for my ignorance, do you think that storing these tuples in rows of a  database for each pixel is way better than storing a transparent bitmap array (size) in a single row? thats because a bitmap array is a ready to use bitmap. Yes, image loss is acceptable

Comment: Color is `4` bytes. Coordinates are, well, `2`-`4` (`byte` - `uint`). If you have `50%` of transparent pixels new method will be better (`25%` save if `byte`) or same (`0` save). For anything more - definitely a win. Arguable a simple compressing of bitmap with transparent pixels may remove more. But you can optimize the offered way further, to example, don't save coordinates for all points, but a path (first point is still `x`,`y`, but next point is a `byte` of offset, if next point is not reachable, start a new path)...

Comment: @Sinatr interesting, i will do some tests, maybe create a method to detect if such printscreen is better to save via bitmap difference or via coordinates/paths. i updates the question, currently im persisting the bitmap after a 7zip compression, don't know if there are better ways to compress.

Comment: To answer the question directly: I can't see where you could get a better compression or a handier format than from the developers of Png.. As an added bonus you can always look at the difference for testing and immediately see the amount and the distribution of the changes.. See my answer for a piece of tested code..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do so using the [code in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26224095/how-to-find-the-difference-between-two-images/26225153?s=1|1.5442#26225153)

It uses `LockBits` and is really fast. It assumes the format to be the native `ARGB` pixel format.

It takes two `Bitmaps` as a parameter and returns the difference `Bitmap`.

The 3rd parameter lets you restore the original from the difference (if you store it losslessly, `Png` is recommended); this was written to allow faster transmission of only the difference image, because for only small differences it allows a much better compression ratio.

This sounds rather similar to your situation, right?

To answer the question directly: I can't see where you could get a better compression or a handier format than from the developers of Png.. As an added bonus you can always **look** at the difference for testing and immediately see the amount and the distribution of the changes..

Comment: Hi, yes its very similar, but as i said, i also use LockBits to get set pixels, and yes, its very fast. I tried to use @Sinatr suggestion to save coordinates and colors into a compressed array, but still, PNG remains the best. So i will mark your answer to close the topic, thanks.