# Image Pixels reading Fastest Method and comparison predefined method

Tags: c#

I want to read the pixels of multiple images and make a comparison with predefined pixels. i am using a method and doing it successfully but this is too slow method and i want a fast method.This is not a good approach.

```
for (int i = 0; i < ht; ++i)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < wid; ++j)
                    {

                        Color pixel = myimage.GetPixel(j, i);

                        if (pixel == Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0)) black++;

                        else if (pixel == Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255)) white++;
                    }
                }`
```

Comment: Search for lockbits! it will be at least 10 times faster.. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26224095/how-to-find-the-difference-between-two-images/26225153#26225153) is an example to study.

Answer (score 0):

Define your black and white colors before your loop, instead of inside your loop so you only do it once.

Comment: I don not know how should i do this .??I need code if you had done it

Comment: You would write color black =  Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0); outside of the loop. But it will not make much of a difference..

Comment: You can't call it black as you already have a variable called that, so you could call it colorBlack or something.  And the same for colorWhite.  Then inside the loop, `if(pixel == colorBlack)` and so on.

Comment: But TaW is right, it will only make a small improvement.  His suggestion of using Bitmap.LockBits certainly looks worth a try!