# Taking Screenshot & Comparing Images

Tags: c#

I'm using these functions below in order to take a screenshot of the user's screen, and compare this screenshot to an image **bmpTest** which is in resources. If finds something compatible with *bmpTest* returns location of it.

**My problem is:** this algorithm used is a little slow and takes about **10-15 seconds** to interpret the image and give a result. Does any of you knows other method which does the same but faster? And with maybe, some % of similarity? I just couldnt find on internet.

```
      private Bitmap Screenshot()
    {
        // this is where we will store a snapshot of the screen
        Bitmap bmpScreenshot = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height);

        // creates a graphics object so we can draw the screen in the bitmap (bmpScreenshot)
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmpScreenshot);

        // copy from screen into the bitmap we created
        g.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Size);

        //g.CopyFromScreen(205, 179, 660, 241, new Size(455, 62));

       // return the screenshot
        return bmpScreenshot;
    }


    private bool FindBitmap(Bitmap bmpNeedle, Bitmap bmpHaystack, out Point location)
    {
        for (int outerX = 0; outerX < bmpHaystack.Width - bmpNeedle.Width; outerX++)
        {
            for (int outerY = 0; outerY < bmpHaystack.Height - bmpNeedle.Height; outerY++)
            {
                for (int innerX = 0; innerX < bmpNeedle.Width; innerX++)
                {
                    for (int innerY = 0; innerY < bmpNeedle.Height; innerY++)
                    {
                        Color cNeedle = bmpNeedle.GetPixel(innerX, innerY);
                        Color cHaystack = bmpHaystack.GetPixel(innerX + outerX, innerY + outerY);

                        if (cNeedle.R != cHaystack.R || cNeedle.G != cHaystack.G || cNeedle.B != cHaystack.B)
                        {
                            goto notFound;
                        }
                    }
                }
                location = new Point(outerX, outerY);
                return true;
            notFound:
                continue;
            }
        }
        location = Point.Empty;
        return false;
    }



    private void button8_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // takes a snapshot of the screen
        Bitmap bmpScreenshot = Screenshot();

        // find the login button and check if it exists
        Point location;
        bool success = FindBitmap(Properties.Resources.bmpTest, bmpScreenshot, out location);

        // check if it found the bitmap
        if (success == false)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Not Found");
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Image Found");
        }            
    }
```

Comment: Instead of Get-SetPixel you should use Lockbits for such analysis. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26224095/how-to-find-the-difference-between-two-images/26225153?s=8|0.3123#26225153) for an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This occurs because every "GetPixel" call on bitmap object performs a lock which is causing your performance issue.

You can get better performance by dealing with the lock yourself, so you can lock the entire bitmap once, in your case both bitmaps, an then iterate through its pixels.

[Check out the code example by Vano Maisuradze](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/240428/Work-with-bitmap-faster-with-Csharp)