# Capture desktop , Make it 256 color and send it over internet

Tags: c#, screen-capture, color-palette, 256color

I am working on a project and in this project I need to capture desktop screen and send it over internet to other client. To compress the image I want to convert it to a 256 color image. I have a general 256 color palette and I am using Euclidean distance to find the nearest color. The problem is that I need to send these images in 10-15 frames per second and making a 256 color image takes 7 seconds. I am wondering how other programs (like teamviewer or real VNC ) are doing this.

```
for (int y=0;y<900;y++) //loop through the height
     for (int x=0;x<1600;x++) //loop through the width
         for (int p=0;p<256;p++) //loop through palette colors
             {
                calculate Euclidean distance of each pixel for each color in pallette and 
                 find the nearest color
                 ** these nested loops take 7 seconds to complete
             }
```

Thanks

Comment: There is no need to convert an image to 256-color, just save the screenshot as a 24-bit PNG or JPEG image and you will have something considerably more legible and still only a few hundred KiB in size.

Comment: VNC uses JPEG compressions for frames, Remote Desktop in Windows uses a different technique that involves more voodoo at the cost of protocol complexity. TeamViewer uses their own protocol that employs some hacks such as color-downsampling but also line-doubling. RDP nowadays employs JPEG compression for fast-moving scenes where their tile approach doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks, But in the end all of these applications have 256-color option and in slow connections they automatically select this option. A 256 color image is around 70-80 KiB and has a reasonable quality. I am looking for the fastest way possible to make a 256 color image in 1/15 seconds.

Comment: Have you considered using palette quantization? If you're using a fixed palette then your images are going to look *horrible*. By using an adaptive-palette then perceivable image quality is improved considerably. See here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa479306.aspx

Comment: @Dai thank you. But all of these methods are very slow and all of them have at least 3 nested loops which obviously is very cpu and time consuming.

Comment: Your simplistic approach requires a machine that can handle 900 x 1600 x 256 x 4 x 15 = 22 gigabytes per second.  It's not that you can't buy it, but it isn't cheap and few users will possess one.  You need to use the kind of code that video encoders use, hand-tuned SIMD code or off-loading the job to the GPU.  Well, don't write your own, this has been done.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks. Could you please explain more or give me some links about it?

Comment: Instead of moving the full info you can try to send only the differences. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30308924/how-do-i-only-send-the-differences-between-two-images-over-the-network/30328038?s=6|0.6114#30328038) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26224095/how-to-find-the-difference-between-two-images/26225153?s=2|1.5584#26225153) for an example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK. After a few days of struggling with many capturing methods and color quantiziers I finally found a solution. Now I am able to send whole desktop image at 10~14 FPS and changed regions of desktop at 20~30 FPS.

In the code I used [rcravens](http://bobcravens.com/2009/04/create-a-remote-desktop-viewer-using-c-and-wcf/)'s classes to capture screen and changes of screen. Then I cropped the image to 10 samll pieces . After that I took small pieces and made them 256-color using an Octree Color Quantizier explained [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa479306.aspx) thanks to @Dai who pointed me to that direction. After color reduction I converted each piece to a byte array and compressed them using LZ4.Net library.

Here is the code:

```
    int all_count = 0;
    Bitmap _desktop = null;

    Bitmap _merged_bitmap = new Bitmap(1600, 900);

    int _height_part_ = 0;
    int _total_rows = 10;
    Bitmap[] crops = null;
    Bitmap[] _new_crops = null;
    Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();

    int _desktop_height = 0;
    int _desktop_width = 0;

    ImageManipulation.OctreeQuantizer _q ;
    RLC.RemoteDesktop.ScreenCapture cap = new RLC.RemoteDesktop.ScreenCapture();



   private void CaptureAndSend()
    {
        sw.Restart();

        //cap = new RLC.RemoteDesktop.ScreenCapture();

        int _left = -1, _top = -1; //Changed regions
        _desktop = cap.Screen(out _left, out _top); //Capture desktop or changed region of it

        if (_desktop == null) return; //if nothing has changed since last capture skip everything

        _desktop_height = _desktop.Height;
        _desktop_width = _desktop.Width;

        // If very small part has changed since last capture skip everything
        if (_desktop_height < 10 || _desktop_width < 10) return; 

        TotalRows(_total_rows); // Calculate the total number of rows 

        crops = new Bitmap[_total_rows]; // Cropped pieces of image
        _new_crops = new Bitmap[_total_rows];

        for (int i = 0; i < _total_rows - 1; i++) //Take whole image and split it into smaller images
            crops[i] = CropRow(i);
        crops[_total_rows - 1] = CropLastRow(_total_rows - 1);


        Parallel.For(0, _total_rows, i =>
        {
            ImageManipulation.OctreeQuantizer _q = new ImageManipulation.OctreeQuantizer(255, 4); // Initialize Octree
            _new_crops[i] = _q.Quantize(crops[i]);

            using (MemoryStream ms=new MemoryStream())
            { 
                _new_crops[i].Save(ms, ImageFormat.Png);
                //Install-Package LZ4.net
                //Compress each part and send them over network
                byte[] data = Lz4Net.Lz4.CompressBytes(ms.ToArray(), Lz4Net.Lz4Mode.HighCompression);

                all_count += data.Length; //Just to check the final size of image
            }                  
        });



        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0:0.0} FPS , {1} seconds , size {2} kb", 1.0 / sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds, sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds.ToString(), all_count / 1024));
        all_count = 0;

    }
    private void TotalRows(int parts)
    {
        _height_part_ = _desktop_height / parts;
    }
    private Bitmap CropRow(int row)
    {
        return Crop(_desktop, new Rectangle(0, row * _height_part_, _desktop_width, _height_part_));
    }
    private Bitmap CropLastRow(int row)
    {
        return Crop(_desktop, new Rectangle(0, row * _height_part_, _desktop_width, _desktop_height - (row * _height_part_)));
    }
 [DllImport("msvcrt.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    private unsafe static extern int memcpy(byte* dest, byte* src, long count);

    private unsafe Bitmap Crop(Bitmap srcImg, Rectangle rectangle)
    {
        if ((srcImg.Width == rectangle.Width) && (srcImg.Height == rectangle.Height))
            return srcImg;

        var srcImgBitmapData = srcImg.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, srcImg.Width, srcImg.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, srcImg.PixelFormat);
        var bpp = srcImgBitmapData.Stride / srcImgBitmapData.Width; // 3 or 4
        var srcPtr = (byte*)srcImgBitmapData.Scan0.ToPointer() + rectangle.Y * srcImgBitmapData.Stride + rectangle.X * bpp;
        var srcStride = srcImgBitmapData.Stride;

        var dstImg = new Bitmap(rectangle.Width, rectangle.Height, srcImg.PixelFormat);
        var dstImgBitmapData = dstImg.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, dstImg.Width, dstImg.Height), ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, dstImg.PixelFormat);
        var dstPtr = (byte*)dstImgBitmapData.Scan0.ToPointer();
        var dstStride = dstImgBitmapData.Stride;

        for (int y = 0; y < rectangle.Height; y++)
        {
            memcpy(dstPtr, srcPtr, dstStride);
            srcPtr += srcStride;
            dstPtr += dstStride;
        }

        srcImg.UnlockBits(srcImgBitmapData);
        dstImg.UnlockBits(dstImgBitmapData);
        return dstImg;
    }
```

I know that my code isn't memory efficient . I'd appreciate it if anyone can help me optimize this code.
Thanks again to my friends  A. Abramov , Dai , HansPassant , TaW and others.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT 2**: I deleted my old post entirely because it was not relevant! by 256 color, I thought you meant, 256 bits - while you are speaking of 256 bytes! I figured that by putting in my calculator your original cordinates (`900 x 900`), and multiplying by 256 for the color. The result was `20,7360,000` bits, which is roughly `2.5 MB`. Compressed, this could reach about `1 MB` - while the bit color equivallent (divided by 8) would be `300 KB` base, and compressed would be much smaller. The solution is simple - this really does take this long to take such an image. Most of the applications you're speaking of, such as teamviewer, have a lower FPS & much lower image quality, based on the computer preformance. Thus, I'm sorry - but the solution is it's probably impossible to do it under the time you requested with a computer like yours.

**EDIT 3**: Hans did the math in the comments under your question - we're talking about `22 GB`. This is not a normal work for an average computer. It's not impossible, but speaking from 2015, it's nowhere near common for a home coputer to handle that much data in a second.

Comment: Thank you, But I think you've missed the point. I know how to capture desktop into bitmap, I want to make it 256-color in 1/15 second to send it over internet as fast as possible

Comment: I'd appreciate it if you tell me which of these methods have parameters to capture in 256-color. I've searched everywhere and I haven't found it yet.

Comment: @user2840253 The second one is PNG, so I'd go with it by default - the third one is also easily capeable of creating 256 color, you just need to tinker with it a little.

Comment: A gif file is about 300 400 KiB in size when saved . I have looked in other methods and I couldn't find any way to take a real 256-color capture. a PNG file might be small in size but making it 256-color compresses it more. and again if you are sure that either of these methods can take 256-color image (like in palettes and color quantization ) I'd appreciate it if you point out the correct set of  parameters to do so.

Comment: @user2840253 [it](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/41030852-8b1a-43f7-8e91-93ef58b81191/save-an-image-in-256-color-png-format?forum=vblanguage) shouldn't be with PNG - PNG is by default 8 bytes when you use `screen.save()`

Comment: thank you, I will look at it. I will also work on Octree-Quantizer for color quantization.

Comment: I tested the code you provided and It doesn't capture 256-color image. I took a picture from my desktop with it and it was about 1MB!!!

Comment: @user2840253 That actually cleared the situation for me. Take a look at the edit.