# Marking differences Between two Pictures

Tags: c#, colors, bitmap

I've written a small programm which compares two png's and saves one of them with the marked differences between the two pictures.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        string a = @"C:\Users\Florian\Desktop\Projects\C# selbst\Compare\Compare\bild1.jpg";
        string b = @"C:\Users\Florian\Desktop\Projects\C# selbst\Compare\Compare\bild2.jpg";

        Bitmap bl = new Bitmap(@a);
        Bitmap br = new Bitmap(@b);

        bool gleich = true;



        if (bl.Size != br.Size)
        {
            gleich = false;
        }
        else
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < bl.Width; x++)
            {
                for (int y = 0; y < bl.Height; y++)
                {
                    if (bl.GetPixel(x, y) != (br.GetPixel(x, y)))
                    {
                        gleich = false;
                        br.SetPixel(x, y, System.Drawing.Color.Red);
                    }
                }
            }
        }


        br.Save(@"C:\Users\Florian\Desktop\myBitmap.png", ImageFormat.Png);
        if (gleich)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("gleich");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("unterschiedlich");
        }

        Console.ReadLine();

    }
}
```

The programm works in that sense that it can differate wether I compare a pictures that I just copied(true) or a picture where i changed a pixel(false). But the new saved png will have marked almost the whole picture in red not only the pixels I changed. Did I do something wrong?

Edit: After the nice answer on this question i added some tolerance for the comparison like this:

```
    private static bool TestPixel(Color c1, Color c2)
    {
        int toleranz = 5;
        int rot = Math.Abs(c1.R - c2.R);
        int grün = Math.Abs(c1.G - c2.G);
        int blau = Math.Abs(c1.B - c2.B);


        if (rot > toleranz || blau > toleranz || grün > toleranz)
            return true;
        return false;
    }
```

Now it works properly thanks :)

Comment: The jpg sources you are using (contrary to your question)will tend to have many tiny differences due to the compression scheme. Try to use actual png sources to see how well your comparison code works..! When you are happy and find it too slow you may want to study [this fast code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26224095/how-to-find-the-difference-between-two-images/26225153?s=2|1.5046#26225153)