# images difference in byte array c#

Tags: c#, image, difference, lockbits

i'm trying to do method that should return difference between two images in byte array(rgb values) and send it via UDP. Code: (there's no part with sending this array because it doesn't matter now)

```
public void getdiff(Bitmap lol,Bitmap lol2)
    {

            Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
            stopWatch.Start();
            Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, lol.Width, lol.Height);
            BitmapData bmpData = lol.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
            IntPtr ptr = bmpData.Scan0;

            Rectangle rect2 = new Rectangle(0, 0, lol2.Width, lol2.Height);
            BitmapData bmpData2 = lol2.LockBits(rect2, ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
            IntPtr ptr2 = bmpData2.Scan0;



            int numBytes = bmpData.Stride * lol.Height;
            byte[] rgbValues = new byte[numBytes];

            int numBytes2 = bmpData2.Stride * lol2.Height;
            byte[] rgbValues2 = new byte[numBytes2];

            byte[] difference = new byte[numBytes];

            Marshal.Copy(ptr, rgbValues, 0, numBytes);
            Marshal.Copy(ptr2, rgbValues2, 0, numBytes2);


            for (int counter = 0; counter < rgbValues.Length; counter++)
            {
                if (rgbValues[counter] != rgbValues2[counter])
                {
                   difference[counter] = rgbValues[counter];

                }

            }

             Marshal.Copy(rgbValues, 0, ptr, numBytes);

            stopWatch.Stop();
            TimeSpan ts = stopWatch.Elapsed;
            textBox1.Text = ts.Milliseconds.ToString();
            lol.UnlockBits(bmpData);
            lol2.UnlockBits(bmpData2);




    }
```

Right now I have 2 byte arrays from 2 images, and I just compare them, when images are different, I write adequate RGB values from chosen image to difference[]. Problem is, when RGB values are equal in both images, adequate places in this difference array are filled with 0(triple 0 represent White colour). So problem is, if i would "impose" this difference[] on to target image it will be probably mostly white. I really want to use Marshal.Copy and Lockbits because it's really efficient.

Question is: How can I store this image difference to avoid for multiplying "for" loops at reading/imposing it? Maybe I'm missing some methods? I would like to stay with LockBits and Marshal.Copy, but if you have better ideas - please share with me.

Comment: You may be intersted to have a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26224095/how-to-find-the-difference-between-two-images/26225153?s=1|0.9954#26225153)

Comment: thanks for you comment, but it is not really effective..
http://imgur.com/j0lN1vf

Comment: Are you sure that the images are really the same (but for the line) and did you use the bitmaps directly or if you used files did you use png and not jpeg?

Comment: Yes, you're right. It works well on Bitmaps, but since Bitmaps are too heavy it doesn't solve my problem. Converting Bitmap to array and then compressing it doesn't solve my problem also, on the other hand converting bitmap to png takes too much time. Or maybe I'm missing something in your code?

Comment: Um, I'm confused: What __are__ you using really, read: What are lol and lol2? Pixelarrays should also work, that after all that is just what the lockbits routine sees; just jpegs will not work because they create different artifacts each time.. When you say Bitmap do you mean BMP, which is just one bitmap format among many. PNG is a good choice for storing the result, imo, as it compresses so effectively

Comment: Sorry, my bad. lol and lol2 are .BMP files. I tried to load .PNG and .JPG as lol and lol2 and looks it doesn't work well with those image formats.

PNG's : http://imgur.com/N6UwSBQ

Comment: Ah, there is more going on here: The result shows that you are not getting the correct pixel layout! You can see how the pattern repeats! Do look into stride and pixelformats!

Comment: Also I'm not really sure what you want me to do. PNG is of course good choice but since LockBits is only for Bitmap and converting Bitmap to Png format later is taking much time it doens't really help me.

Comment: I changed PixelFormat and now it works, hmm, lets say good.
http://imgur.com/tiirgUO

Comment: Please do not confuse Fileformats as tif, png, jped or bmp with .Net Image types like Bitmap, Icon, WMF !!! A Bitmap has __nothing__ to do with a BMP file other that the sound of the name! A .Net Bitmap is just a raster of pixels, so png and tif and jpg are all Bitmaps once you read them into an Image/Bitmap. Note that the code in my post __assumes__ ARGB but your BitMapData are 24bpp so you need to either modify it a little ` int Bpp = 4;` <==3 or create your bitmaps in a 32bpp format.

Comment: The reason for choosing png for the output format is that it compresses so well and the resulting file size can be __transmitted__ much more efficiently than any other storage I can think of..

Comment: Sorry for this missunderstanding with bitmaps/bmps.. Anyway what I want to say is : the main thing here is efficiency, so If I want reach "20FPS" I have to execute your method about 20 times, and then impose picture difference after it. It takes about 80-100 ms, so it gives us about 10fps which is equal result to result of sending whole .png files via udp(sometimes shared on 2,3 packets).

Comment: Somehow applications like TeamViewer does that with like 25FPS and I'm trying to work out how they do it..

Comment: It should look like this : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mfQsKXGyVQI
about 8:30
But solution of this guy may be not really adequate for this kind of problem, because he does all in area of 1 computer, so he doesn't care about capacity of arrays etc.
Sorry for a bit messy comments, hope you understood all.

Comment: You may also take a look at this 
http://pastebin.com/XqigWMYZ
I tried this solution also, but its even longer.

Comment: Not sure if I can help any further then. One thing to try would be to test if using `PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb` for all bitmaps from start to end. According to Hans Passant this is __by far the fastest__ format.

Comment: thanks for your time anyway.