# How to compare two images and display the difference between the two images in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms

[image]

As shown in the above figure, the output should be displayed like this.
Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Can you please explain in more details what you're trying to achieve here?

Comment: what kind of compare are you talking about ? compare by size or compare by images .

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Please explicate.

Comment: Sadly being unclear doesn't perhaps matter as the question is arguably too broad and if so off-topic for SO. [ask].  Wishing you well

Comment: Sry , If prize is present in those 2 images that should be displayed .https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yi0c0.jpg

Comment: You may want to study [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26224095/how-to-find-the-difference-between-two-images/26225153?s=1|49.1682#26225153)..

Comment: You dont want to compare the difference in color between the two images you want to get the different text. This is no trivial job. You probably need algorithms that get text from images.

Answer (score 0):

Equal points are the ones that make this equality true -binary operation-: "image1 pixel" AND "image2 pixel" == "image1 pixel"

If you're working with Bitmap class, you have a Pixels array where you can apply this kind of comparison